# How to correct a word of a student if it is grammatically false

Tags: grammar, spelling, grammaticality

When a word of anybody includes an grammatical error,how could one confirm, does my correction make a sense

> Man musste so "X" schreiben, statt "Y"

Comment: Just checking: Are you sure you want to talk about grammar and not spelling?

Comment: Grammatically correction when a students writing is false

Answer (score 6):

Wenn die Grammatikregel, nach der es falsch war, immer noch in Kraft ist, muss es heißen:

> Man muss "X" schreiben, statt "Y".

Das 'so', wenn es sich darauf bezieht, dass im Satz davor die Regel genannt wird, sollte durch ein 'also' ersetzt werden.

> Die dritte Person Singular von 'essen' ist 'isst'. Man muss also 'isst' schreiben, statt 'esse'.

'Statt' ist prima, aber 'nicht' geht auch.

Wenn die Regel eine historische ist, die nicht mehr gilt, muss man  'musste' schreiben, nicht 'muss'.

Man kann aber auch 'musste' schreiben statt 'muss', wenn man den Aspekt, dass es eine Handlung in der Vergangenheit war, besonders betonen will.

> Ich war so aufgeregt! Mein Wellensittich war am Vorabend gestorben. Ich war abgelenkt und verwirrt. Dann kam dieser vertrackte Satz! Man musste 'isst' statt 'esse' schreiben und ich hab's übersehen.

Comment: Huch? Kommt im Deutschen wirklich ein Komma vor "statt" im ersten Beispiel?

Comment: @Robert: Es ist möglich, wenn man den _statt_-Teil als Nachtrag auffassen möchte. Ich würde allerdings keines setzen.